# How to shift down block in css

Tags: html, css

I'm new in web design. 
I'm trying to finish a school project. I would like to create this effect on my website. As you can see the green block was shifted down and is now overlapping the next row which has a grey background. Do you know any css that could do that? thanks!! [image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: `transform:translate(x)`, `position:relative` + `top` or `bottom`, negative bottom `margin`, have you tried anythings like this ?

Answer (score 0):

set css style for green box like below:

```
.green-box{
    position: relative;
    top: 32px;
 }
```

this is one of the hundreds of ways.
in this way set `position: relative;` and set a distance from top, you can also set negative number of px for distance from top like `top: -32px;`
you have to try several distances from top to get result

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your markup, there are quite a few ways you can achieve this.

In [this linked pen](https://codepen.io/alesc/pen/mdJVwzo) you can see an example using relative positioning, however I suggest reading [this article](https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/advanced-positioning/) as it's a deep dive into positioning `html` elements using `css`.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but one of the easiest ways and probably least affecting the layout could be using negative margin and translate.

You can check out the example below.

I have 3 `<div>` elements that use relative position and have a fixed height for the example.

The `z-index` controls the positioning of elements one over the other.

The `margin: 0 20px -50px;` part allows for the element to be moved above the bottom element. The number `-50px` varies depending on the height of the element you want to position. In this case the element's height is exactly `50px`.

After that the `transform: translate(0, -50%);` part moves the element vertically based on the element itself thus, centering it in combination with the height.

In order to adjust the internal spacing of each element to accommodate content you can play with each element's padding and adjust dimensions accordingly.

Run the snippet to check out how it works out.

```css
.red, .blue {
   height: 100px;
   z-index: 5;
   position: relative;
}

.red {
   background: #dcc;
}

.blue {
   background: #ccd;
}

.green {
   position: relative;
   background: #cdc;
   margin: 0 20px -50px;
   z-index: 10;
   line-height: 20px;
   transform: translate(0, -50%);
   padding: 15px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green">I am the middle content</div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```